# Fonts appearing on Browserify livereload but not on refresh in Chrome only

Tags: css, font-face, browserify, stylus, livereload

This is one of the stranger errors I've seen in a while.

Using browserify, I modify my stylus css file so that I set a `font-family` that links to a library defined with `@font-face`.

When I refresh my page, my page does not show the fonts in use.

However, if I make a change to my stylus files and it livereloads, the fonts are visible. If I refresh from there, the font styles do not take effect.

The problem exists only in Chrome.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I ended up needing to base64 the fonts.